# Use a field in inherited model on odoo

Tags: python, odoo

It is a very simple question. I want to use a field from inherited model, here is my balance.py

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class Balance_res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
```

And balance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
<record id="balance_res_partner_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="priority" eval="3"/>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <button name="toggle_active" position="before">
                <button class="oe_stat_button" type="action" name="%(account.action_account_payments)d"
                            attrs="{'invisible': [('customer', '=', False)]}"
                            icon="fa-usd">
                            <field string="Balance" name="credit" widget="statinfo"/>
                </button>
            </button>
        </field>
        </record>
    </odoo>
```

As you see, I don't have any 'credit' field in balance.py, so server doesn't run. The trick I want to do is to use 'credit' field from res.partner, and show its in that button value.

Help needed. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inherit the fields of res.partner you must change **_name** per **_inherit**

And, one question, what do you want to do with that field?

**EDITED:**

About how to show credit, i made a little changes in the code:

balance.py

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api


class ProductLot(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    credit_2 = fields.Char(
        string='Balance',
        compute='_compute_credit_2',
    )

    @api.multi
    def _compute_credit_2(self):
        for record_id in self:
            record_id.credit_2 = str(record_id.credit)
```

And balance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="balance_res_partner_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">balance.res.partner.form.view</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="3"/>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//button[@name='toggle_active']" position="after">
                    <button type="action"
                            name="%(account.action_account_payments)d"
                            attrs="{'invisible': [('customer', '=', False)]}"
                            class="oe_stat_button"
                            icon="fa-usd">
                        <field name="credit_2" widget="statinfo"/>
                    </button>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

For me that works perfect.

If you use credit field, the button text lokks like *0,0& nbsp;€*, that's why i use another field.

Regards

Comment: Sorry, the code is edited, it is _inherit. I want to make a button, like a 'sell count' button in contact form. When you click it, it redirects you to payment model, actually I did this part. The redirection is ok, but I want to see credit of customer as a string of newly Balance button.